# Installing Tikz-Feynman

Tags: tikz-feynman

I am a novice and I a have no idea how to install Tikz-Feynman from scratch. I have downloaded the source code and I would like to install it on mac. Could anybody please help me installing the package?

Thank you.

Comment: Which distribution do you have? Is it tex live 2016?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your interest in [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman).  Since the package is available on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman), all you really need to do is make sure your distribution is up to date which is well described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/26980).

If, for any reason, you can't update your distribution, you can still install the package in your local TEXMF tree.  Firsty, you'll need to obtain the package files from either [project page](http://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) or [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman).  Next, you'll need to locate your local TEXMF tree, and there are instructions for that in other questions ([Linux / Unix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/26980), [Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/26980)).

In the end, you should have all the files in:

```
$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/tikz-feynman/<package files>
```

Note that Ti*k*Z-Feynman contains a few extra files in addition to the usual `.cls` files and just to be safe, you should copy them all.